# Javascript: Open new window and copy over css references from the current window

Tags: javascript, css

I want to open a new window and copy over the css references from the current window so that my new window has the same styling. What I've tried is the following:

```
var externalWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=600,height=400,left=200,top=200');
var headElements = window.document.head.childNodes;
for(var i = 0; i < headElements.length; i++)
{
    externalWindow.document.head.appendChild(headElements[i]);
}
```

However, when I inspect the head element using devTools in the new window, the head element is empty. Using a debugger I can see that headElements is correctly getting the head elements from the current page and appendChild is running on all of them.

If I run:

```
externalWindow.document.body.appendChild(window.document.getElementById("MyElement"));
```

It copies over an element to the body, so why can't I copy over elements in the head?

Comment: Note that without `.cloneNode(true)` you’re not _copying_ nodes, you’re moving them. This partially explains why it doesn’t fully work. It works for me, but only every second element; the `NodeList` from `document.head.childNodes` loses its elements as they get removed from the DOM, so the index `i` skips over every second element.

Comment: Ok, using .cloneNode(true) successfully copies over all the <link> elements which reference the css files, but the styling doesn't seem to be applied. Perhaps because the href in those <link> elements is set to "/css/myfile.min.css" and because it's not an absolute path, the new window doesn't know what domain to get it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before opening the new document, you could create a `STYLE` tag in the existing document and populate that with all of the styles from either the `LINK` or `STYLE` tags in the header.  You could then just copy that tag into the end of the new document.

Something like the following:

```js
function showStyles() {
  let ss = document.styleSheets;
  let copycss = document.createElement("style");
  // div just to show that styles are being found
  let copydiv = document.getElementById("copiedstyles");
  for (let i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < ss[i].cssRules.length; j++) {
      let css = ss[i].cssRules[j].cssText;
      copycss.innerHTML += css + "\n";
      // Just for testing
      copydiv.innerHTML += css + "<br>";
    }
  }
  copycss.innerHTML += "button {color:purple;}\n";
  copydiv.innerHTML += "button {color:purple;}<br>";
  document.body.appendChild(copycss);
}
```

```css
.blah {color:red;}
button {color:green;}
```

```html
<button onclick="showStyles();">Show styles</button>
<div id="copiedstyles"></div>
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't include the copying of the tag into the new document, just the creation of a new tag in the existing document that can then be copied using whatever method you wish.

Comment: Also note that the snippet will generate styles for this page as well.

Comment: This worked but I had to surround the inner for loop with a try catch, due to some styles being not able to copy due to CORS policy, although the ones which did copy were enough to do what I needed. It's also a little slow if you have large style sheets.

Comment: I had to go for this solution, because I use style-components, and by default they inject styles with CSSOM which causes its own <style> tag to look empty (no innerHTML). This way I could extract all rules. I'm not sure if that helps with performance, but I built the final string first, and applied to innerHTML once.

Answer (score 3):

as simple as:

```
document.head.querySelectorAll('link, style').forEach(htmlElement => {
     newWindow.document.head.appendChild(htmlElement.cloneNode(true));
});
```